# Android services method not calling from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have service which include connecting to `bluetooth` device.I'm calling this service from my first activity. And service successfully created and started . But when i use bind in first activity to call method in service, its not executing. I referred to [LocalService example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

**My service code:**

```
 // Binder given to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // A client is binding to the service with bindService()
    return mBinder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BluetoothServices getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return BluetoothServices.this;
    }

}

public void SendData(){
    Log.d("msg", "Send msg"); 
}
```

I'm using below code in my **first activity:**

```
BluetoothServices mService;
boolean mBound = false;

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
     Intent btservices = new Intent(getApplication(),BluetoothServices.class);
     startService(btservices);

     bindService(btservices, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(mBound){
        mService.SendData();
    }
}
```

What is the problem in above code?Why it is not binding and calling method?

My manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_50"
    android:theme="@style/app_theme" >

    <service android:name="com.example.utilities.BluetoothServices"></service>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pkg.Thisisit"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Have you looked in the logcat? Any errors or other useful logs?

Comment: @DavidWasser Actually when i call that method within if(mBound) 'm not getting any error.But i call out side, getting NullPointer exception.That my be because of No Binding.

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Comment: @DavidWasser See edited question, i added manifest. can you tel me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the problem in above code?Why it is not binding and calling method?

Order of operations.  The order of lifecycle callbacks when the Activity starts is

1. onCreate()
2. onStart()
3. onResume()

In your code, you check if the `Service` is bound and call the send data method in `onCreate()`, but don't bind to the `Service` until `onStart()`, so your first block of code will never trigger since you are never bound at that point.

A couple other points to note:

- Service binding is asynchronous.  Even if you reorder your calls so `SendData()` were in `onResume()` the `Service` would still not likely be ready; the `Service` is not immediately bound after you call `bindService()`.  That's what `ServiceConnection` is for, it tells you when the Service is available with the `onServiceConnected()` callback.  You must wait for this before accessing anything.
- When binding to a Service, you don't also have to start it.  A bound Service is started on binding if it is not already running.  In the above code, the call to `startService()` is superfluous.

Comment: Thank you, i change the order of operation. And i call the method, sendData() in OnServiceConnected(),..it works fine,Great. But in my case,i need to bind from different activities,not only from First activity. In other Activities, if i have some button, when i click on that i need to call sendData() method.How can i do that?

Comment: Simply call `sendData()` from your button's click handler.  The timing sensitivity really only applies if you are trying to reach the Service while the Activity is starting up.  Binding doesn't take a long time, it just doesn't happen inline with the code.